# GitHub branching strategy for "servers" and "releases"

Tags: git, github, github-actions, branching-and-merging

I am trying to wrap my head around creating a practical strategy for GitHub branches and deployments to multiple servers using GitHub Actions.

I have the following four servers:

1. Dev server
2. QA server
3. Staging server
4. Production server

Note that, while one version of the app (say 1.0) may be on the Staging server, a newer version of the app (say 1.1) may already be on the QA server, and so on.

Since I want to use GitHub Actions for deployment to those servers, I thought it would be a good idea to make one branch per server, and then create a corresponding GitHub Action that builds the app and pushes it to the corresponding server whenever a push is made to the respective branch. Example: If I push to the QA branch, the GitHub action builds the app and deploys it to the QA server.

This works. However, I am getting a little confused. Because I also read about the concept of "release branches", and I've noticed that some open source repos utilise "releases".

In my version, let's call it "server-based branches", a branch corresponds to a server. But I am wondering: Should a branch rather corresponds to a version of the code, e.g. one branch for release-1.0, another branch for release-1.1, and so on?

How do people handle this challenge?

PS: I need to be able to make hotfixes to individual servers as well.

Comment: Not thinking about Git for a moment, how do you currently determine what gets deployed to each server?

Comment: @TTT I'm not sure what you mean? I make a build and upload it to the relevant server!?

Comment: I mean how you decide what build to put on each server, and when. I think the production server is obvious, but what about the others? For example, how do Dev, QA, and Stage differ?

Answer (score 0):

I definitely wouldn't setup a branch for each development environment but instead use a matrix.

Some nice information and guidance can be found in this post:
https://yonatankra.com/7-github-actions-tricks-i-wish-i-knew-before-i-started/